# Determine the n-th derivative $g^{(n)} (1)$ of $g$ at $z = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the complex function $g(z) = \frac{3iz-6i}{z-3}$

I need to determine the n-th derivative $g^{(n)} (1)$ of $g$ at $z = 1, n>0$

I tried rewriting $g(z) = g(a+bi) = \frac{3i(a+bi)-6i}{a+bi-3}$

So $g(z) = \frac{3ia}{a+bi-3} + \frac{3bi}{a+bi-3} - \frac{6i}{a+bi-3}$

I don't seem to be making any ground though.

Could someone help me understand the general approach for this.

I'm guessing this would also be helpful if I'm trying to find some power(taylor) series.

I'm more interested in the approach rather than the answer, exams coming up.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that

$$g(z) = 3i\frac{z-2}{z-3} = 3i + 3i \frac{1}{z-3}$$

So, $g^{(n)}(z) = 3i \left( (z-3)^{-1} \right)^{(n)}$

But $$\left( (z-3)^{-1} \right)^{(n)} = (-1)^n n! (z-3)^{-(n+1)}$$

So $g^{(n)}(1) = -3i\frac{n!}{2^{n+1}}$

Comment: Can I ask how you got from $3i \frac{z-2}{z-3}$ to $3i+3i \frac{1}{z-3}$, I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't see it. Thanks.

Comment: @GregoryPeck :  $\frac{z-2}{z-3} = \frac{z-3+1}{z-3} = \frac{z-3}{z-3}+ \frac{1}{z-3} = 1+\frac{1}{z-3}$

Comment: Did you get the result for $((z-3)^{-1})^{(n)}$ by trying a few values of $n$ and recognising a formula? Or did you do it another way?

Comment: @GregoryPeck : I know this formula "by heart", but you can find it by a quick induction : $\frac{1}{x}' = -\frac{1}{x^2}$, $\frac{1}{x^2}' = - 2 \frac{1}{x^3}$, etc.